# Change operating system language of ubuntu after insallaled

Tags: 12.04

I recently installed ubuntu 12.04 in my PC. Its running fine. But unfortunately I have been select **Albanian** language. Actually I want to **English(US)**. Can I change **Albanian** to  **English(US)** as my os?? Please give any idea.

Answer (score 1):

- Open Language support from Dash.
- Select English(US) language and then apply it system wide.
- Now it works.

Comment: Thanks for answered. I want to set **English(US)** as default language for all user and also all over hole operating system.

Comment: yes,English(US) will be set as default and system wide language.

Comment: Sorry, I'm followed your solution and restart my computer and then log in my system. This time it shows selected language as Albanian ion right-top corner, And given Password also take as Albanian layout. Any other solution?

Comment: Change the keyboard layout to English(US) from text entry.

Comment: Can you explain more regarding keyboard layout? It will be helpful for me.

Comment: search for text entry in dash,and then open it.click the + option to add English(US) source for keyboard text entry.Now select the English(US) option on the keyboard layout icon in the top panel.

Comment: yes, I got it and it require change manually. Please tell me one think. I can not setting this as default ? As like if I choose English language  at first time.

Comment: if you select that,then the selected keyboard layout will appears as default.

Comment: yes, Its appears as default but when I restart it that again.